# How do I vertically center align my main div?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to create a simple card box page, based on a Frontend Mentor challenge(https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/order-summary-component-QlPmajDUj), but I am really struggling to vertically align the main card.

I want it to be responsive for smaller screen sizes (mobile) but as you can see in the demo page, the card moves around if user grabs the page. I want it to be static and that the card -and it's elements- adapts(shrink or expands) to different screen sizes.

This is my first CSS experiment, so I don't know much what to do.

Demo page: https://card-style-test.w3spaces.com/

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Red+Hat+Display:wght@500;700;900&display=swap");

:root {
    --pale-blue: hsl(225, 100%, 94%);
    --bright-blue: hsl(245, 75%, 52%);
    --very-pale-blue: hsl(225, 100%, 98%);
    --desaturated-blue: hsl(224, 23%, 55%);
    --dark-blue: hsl(223, 47%, 23%);
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    background-image: url(/assets/images/pattern-background-desktop.svg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: var(--pale-blue);
    font-family: "Red Hat Display", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    min-width: 375px;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

/* ----------Card---------- */
.card {
    max-width: 450px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    box-shadow: 0px 18px 25px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.64);
}

/* ----------Mobile Responsiveness---------- */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .card {
        width: 90%;
        margin: auto auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-img"><img src="/assets/images/illustration-hero.svg" alt=""></div>

    <div class="summary-info">
      <h4>
        Order Summary
      </h4>
      <p>
        You can now listen to millions of songs, audiobooks, and podcasts on any
        device anywhere you like!
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="plan-box-all">
      <div class="plan-box-inner fit-pb">
        <div class="plan-icon">
          <img src="/assets/images/icon-music.svg" alt="music note beside price info">
        </div>
        <div class="plan-price fit-pb">
          <h4>Annual Plan</h4>
          <p>$59.99/year</p>
        </div>
        <div class="plan-changer fit-pb">
          <a href="#">Change</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="btns">
      <a href="#" class="pay-btn">Proceed to Payment</a>
      <a href="#" class="cancel-btn">Cancel Order</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please make sure your code is a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what size you refer to as *mobile*, your body CSS has a fixed min-width: `min-width: 375px`. So any screen smaller than 375px is going to overflow and won't resize to the window, but rather the min-width.

Add the following:

```
@media(max-width:400px){
  body {
    min-width: unset;
  }
}
```